# CSLA Editable Grid

Tags: c#, csla

Which [CSLA framework](https://cslanet.com/) *stereotype* should be used with an editable presentation grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A book would be a good starting point. You would more than likely need a BLB (BusinessListBase) such as a EditableRootList and EditableRoot stereotype. It is very easy to accomplish this. Depending on the control you need to Set the BLB as the DataSource, call DataBind and BeginEdit()/EndEdit().

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you use BusinessListBase for any collection that is editable.  I would advise reading the chapter on Data Binding in the CSLA book, as it provides the details on how to implement data binding depending upon the front end you are using (Windows Forms, Web Forms or WPF).